# fill matrix with numbers in each row to create a parttern

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a trip parttern using a matrix.

```
    Glastonbury Munich Venice Paris Ibiza Kamar-Taj
 [1,]           1      2      3     4     5         6
 [2,]           1      2      3     4     5         0
 [3,]           1      2      3     4     0         0
 [4,]           1      2      3     0     0         0
 [5,]           1      2      0     0     0         0
 [6,]           3      2      1     4     5         6
 [7,]           0      2      3     4     1         0
 [8,]           0      1      2     0     0         0
 [9,]           5      1      3     2     0         0
```

each row represents a single trip, and the number in a cell represents the order they visited each locations. Zero means they didn't visit that place.

currently I'm creating it like this:

```
tripMatrix <- list()

tripMatrix[[ 1 ]] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
tripMatrix[[ 2 ]] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 3 ]] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 4 ]] <- c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 5 ]] <- c(1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 6 ]] <- c(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6)
tripMatrix[[ 7 ]] <- c(0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 8 ]] <- c(4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 8 ]] <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)
tripMatrix[[ 10 ]] <- c(5, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0)

trips <- matrix(unlist(tripMatrix), ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

I can only do this for a few rows,  but I'll like to generate N number of rows with different conbinations of places visited during a trip.

Please I can I do this for N number of rows without  having to manually create a list of trips?

Comment: Is 0 the only value that can be repeated ?

Comment: i think the theoretical number of rows is 6! + 6C5*5! + 6C4*4! + 6C3*3! + 6C2*2! + 6C1. do you want all of 1956 rows?

Comment: @CarlesSansFuentes I think so. Since you cannot be present at different places at the same time :P

Comment: @chinsoon12, Yes all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with a math approach by thinking about the theoretical number of trips. For example, out of the 6 places, you can choose 4 to visit (i.e. 6C4 = 6 choose 4) and among these 4 places, you can visit them in any order giving 4! (4 factorial) ways of visiting them in different sequence. The same applies to other number of places, giving a theoretical number of  6! + 6C5*5! + 6C4*4! + 6C3*3! + 6C2*2! + 6C1 = 1956 possible trips.

Here is an option using `utils::combn` and `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral` to generate all 1,956 possibilities:

```
nc <- 6L
l <- lapply(1L:nc, function(n) combn(1L:nc, n, 
    function(x) {
        if (length(x) > 1L) {
            p <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(x, length(x))
            a <- matrix(0L, nrow=nrow(p), ncol=nc)
            a[cbind(c(row(p)), c(p))] <- col(p)
        } else {
            a <- integer(nc)
            a[x] <- 1L
        }
        a
    }, simplify=FALSE))

m <- do.call(rbind, unlist(l, recursive=FALSE))
```

`head(m, 20)`:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
 [7,]    1    2    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    2    1    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    1    0    2    0    0    0
[10,]    2    0    1    0    0    0
[11,]    1    0    0    2    0    0
[12,]    2    0    0    1    0    0
[13,]    1    0    0    0    2    0
[14,]    2    0    0    0    1    0
[15,]    1    0    0    0    0    2
[16,]    2    0    0    0    0    1
[17,]    0    1    2    0    0    0
[18,]    0    2    1    0    0    0
[19,]    0    1    0    2    0    0
[20,]    0    2    0    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sample` and `replicate` like :

```
N <- 10
unique_trip_locations <- 6

t(replicate(N, sample(0:unique_trip_locations, unique_trip_locations)))


#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    2    3    1    5    0    6
# [2,]    5    3    6    2    0    1
# [3,]    2    4    1    3    0    5
# [4,]    1    6    5    3    0    2
# [5,]    6    3    1    4    2    0
# [6,]    1    2    0    6    5    4
# [7,]    5    1    3    0    4    6
# [8,]    0    4    6    2    3    1
# [9,]    0    5    1    3    2    6
#[10,]    5    6    0    1    3    2
```

However, this has got one limitation that 0 can occur max only once like all other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use brute force to do it, and in this case it is totally feasible. 
I think mine is clearer than the previous answers:

```
vector<-c(1:6, rep(0,6))  # This is what you need as combinations
Data<-data.frame()        # Initilizing Dataframe
i<-1                      # Just to check total iterations
N<-1956                   # Number of unique combinations to get

while(nrow(Data)<=N){
  i<- i+1
  Data<- rbind(Data,sample(vector, 6, replace = F))
  Data<-Data[!duplicated(Data),]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution without using any additional packages:

```
# define your own permutation function
perm <- function(x) {
  if (length(x)==1) return(t(x))
  subset(r <- do.call(expand.grid,replicate(length(x),x,simplify = F)), colSums(apply(r, 1, duplicated))==0)
}

# define function that give all permutations with given number of posistions
f <- function(x,vl) {
  p <- perm(x)
  unname(t(apply(p, 1, function(q) replace(rep(0,vl),q,seq_along(q)))))
}

# generate the desired output
v = 1:6
res <- do.call(rbind,
               Map(f, 
                   vl = length(v),
                   unlist(sapply(seq_along(v), function(k) combn(v,k,simplify = F)),recursive = F)))
```

such that

```
> head(res,25)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    1
 [7,]    2    1    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    1    2    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    2    0    1    0    0    0
[10,]    1    0    2    0    0    0
[11,]    2    0    0    1    0    0
[12,]    1    0    0    2    0    0
[13,]    2    0    0    0    1    0
[14,]    1    0    0    0    2    0
[15,]    2    0    0    0    0    1
[16,]    1    0    0    0    0    2
[17,]    0    2    1    0    0    0
[18,]    0    1    2    0    0    0
[19,]    0    2    0    1    0    0
[20,]    0    1    0    2    0    0
[21,]    0    2    0    0    1    0
[22,]    0    1    0    0    2    0
[23,]    0    2    0    0    0    1
[24,]    0    1    0    0    0    2
[25,]    0    0    2    1    0    0
```